# Can't connect to database from snapshot. Ubuntu 18.04 postgres 9.5

Tags: linux, database, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to database restored from disk snapshot. I have new VM with ubuntu 18.04. I installed postgres, postgres-client and postgres-contrib from *.deb files. Then I mounted managed disk into machine with database and tried to connect - no success.

Postgres server running good, cluster ok, status ok, pg_isready ok. **Until** I change the data_directory in `postgresql.conf` from default to mounted -  `/snapshot_data_path/`. After that my cluster is down and I cannot use psql in postgres (error ~ .s.PGSQL missing. File dissapearing from default directory).

`chown -R to /snapshot_data_path` - done, looks ok.

I think my database is running manualy when I use :

`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -d 3 -D /database/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` with that new path. EDIT: Error, I can connect but no data inside.

I try search over the internet for similar problems - no luck.

Is it possible to take database from 1 VM and connect it with another fresh VM? Or I must use pg_dump to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here the official documentation on this topic: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/backup-file.html

> The database server must be shut down in order to get a usable backup.

Did you shutdown the server while the data snapshot was taken?

Comment: Yep, it is stopped. I spend to much time on this right now. Change aproach into pg_dump / pg_restore. Thanks You anyway.